# Rails - Caching all the users with a specific attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

In a Rails 6 app, I have a page that shows all the users who are admins.
Since the list changes very seldom I'd like to cache the fragment.

How can I handle such a cache?

I suppose to invalidate it I should have some kind of `after_save` callback in the user model to check if the saved user just became an admin or he's not anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for callbacks. You can set cache key, so every time there is new admin, key will change and new cache will be generated. For example:

```
<% cache "admin-list-#{@admins.count}" do %>
  <% @admins.each do |admin| %>
    <%= admin.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In case when admin details will change and number of admin users will be the same, you can use collection caching:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#collection-caching

```
<%= render partial: 'users/admin', collection: @admins, cached: true %>
```

To test caching in development use this command:
`rails dev:cache`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How about the case when the number of admins doesn't change. I.e. Tony is removed from admin while Bob is added?

Comment: i think better way for this case will be collection caching, i will update my answer

Comment: Collection cache seems just what I was looking for. Thanks.